# python deeplearning softmax with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

I implemented softmax with numpy.
As you can see in the code, we have a matrix and we want to get the softmax for the row.
For example, the soft max for row 1 is calculated by dividing np.sum(np.exp([1,3,6,-3,1]) by 1,3,5,-3,1
The soft max for line 2 is to find the soft max for np.sum(np.exp([5,2,1,4,3]). How do I do this?

```
def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x),axis=1)
x = np.array([[1,3,6,-3,1],
              [5,2,1,4,3]])


print(softmax(x))
print(f"1:{softmax(x)[0]} sum : {np.sum(softmax(x)[0])}")
print(f"2:{softmax(x)[1]} sum : {np.sum(softmax(x)[1])}")
```

> ---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-261-eb8c9feae03f> in <module>
      5 
      6 
----> 7 print(softmax(x))
      8 print(f"1:{softmax(x)[0]} sum : {np.sum(softmax(x)[0])}")
      9 print(f"2:{softmax(x)[1]} sum : {np.sum(softmax(x)[1])}")

<ipython-input-261-eb8c9feae03f> in softmax(x)
      1 def softmax(x):
----> 2     return np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x),axis=1)
      3 x = np.array([[1,3,6,-3,1],
      4               [5,2,1,4,3]])
      5 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,5) (2,) 
>
```

Comment: FYI: SciPy has the `softmax` function since version 1.2.0: [`scipy.special.softmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.softmax.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `sum(exp(x), axis=1)` returns a 1-D numpy array. Change it to `sum(esp(x), axis=1, keepdims=True)` to avoid numpy from automatically dropping one dimension.

```py
def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x),axis=1, keepdims=True)

x = np.array([[1,3,6,-3,1],
              [5,2,1,4,3]])


print(softmax(x))
print(f"1:{softmax(x)[0]} sum : {np.sum(softmax(x)[0])}")
print(f"2:{softmax(x)[1]} sum : {np.sum(softmax(x)[1])}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `reshape` `np.sum` result.

```py
np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=1).reshape(2,1)
```

instead of

```py
np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=1)
```

More generic way, you can use below statement.

```py
return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x),axis=1).reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
```